# How to split multi-formatted lines

Tags: linux, bash, split

I'm having a problem in splitting multi-formatted lines. I want to get all the gateway from command `route -n`. All I know is using `cut`, but it doesn't work.

Assume that my `route -n` shows the following message:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.12.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.12.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
```

I want to get: `192.168.12.2` and `192.168.12.1`

Answer (score 1):

#### File process.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{                              \
  if(FNR > 1)                  \
  {                            \
    printf $2"\n";             \
  }                            \
}                              \
```

#### Sample input.txt

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.12.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.12.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
```

#### Output

```
$ ./process.awk input.txt
192.168.12.2
192.168.12.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
route -n | awk 'FNR > 1 {print $2}'
```

Output:

```
192.168.12.2
192.168.12.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the cut command, you can do it this way:

```
route -n | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2 | grep "[0-9]"
```

Note: Here the second column is the gateway IP address column (in numbers) in "route -n" command output.